# Пролистывание страниц сайта

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать пролистывание страниц, как на этом [сайте](https://www.epicgames.com/unrealtournament/#splash)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это при помощи библиотеки `FullPage.js`
Смотреть пример обязательно на в развёрнутом виде (справа снизу кнопка "В развёрнутом виде" после запуска сниппета)

```js
    var $header_top = $('.header-top');
    var $nav = $('nav');
    $header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
    });

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#c2c0bd', '#687799', '#bba286', '#678366', '#B8B89F'],
        sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
        slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
        navigation: true,
        slidesNavigation: true,
        controlArrows: false,
        anchors: ['firstSection', 'secondSection', 'thirdSection', 'fourthSection', 'fifthSection'],
        menu: '#menu',

        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
            $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
            $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
            if (index == 5) {
                $('#fp-nav').hide();
            }
        },
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
            if(index == 5) {
                $('#fp-nav').show();
            }
        },

        afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
            if(anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
                $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, 'up');
                $header_top.css('background', 'transparent');
                $nav.css('background', 'transparent');
                $(this).css('background', '#374140');
                $(this).find('h2').css('color', 'white');
                $(this).find('h3').css('color', 'white');
                $(this).find('p').css(
                    {
                        'color': '#DC3522',
                        'opacity': 1,
                        'transform': 'translateY(0)'
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        onSlideLeave: function( anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
            if(anchorLink == 'fifthSection' && slideIndex == 1) {
                $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'up');
                $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
                $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,400,700);

    @font-face {
        font-family: "untitled-font-1";
        src:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot");
        src:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff"),
        url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg");
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    [class^="icon-"]:after,
    [class*=" icon-"]:after {
        font-family: "untitled-font-1";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        speak: none;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    .icon-up-open-big { display: inline-block; }

    .icon-up-open-big:after {
        content: "a";
        font-size: 2.5em;
        display: block;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
        color: black;
        -webkit-transition: color .3s;
        transition: color .3s;
    }

    .icon-up-open-big:hover:after {
        color: white;
    }

    .scroll-icon {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 30px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .l-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .l-right {
        float: right;
    }

    .end {
        margin-top: 30px;
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(300px);
        transform: translateY(300px);
        -webkit-transition: opacity, -webkit-transform 1s;
        transition: opacity, transform 1s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
        transition-delay: 1s;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
    }

    body {
        color: black;
        letter-spacing: .18em;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    ul, li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .header-top {
        background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .3);
        height: 70px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 12;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    h1 {
        line-height: 70px;
        height: 70px;
    }

    h1 a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .toggle-menu {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .toggle-menu i {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        background: white;
        width: 30px;
        left: 10px;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .toggle-menu i:nth-child(1) {
        top: 16px;
    }

    .toggle-menu i:nth-child(2) {
        top: 24px;
    }

    .toggle-menu i:nth-child(3) {
        top: 32px;
    }

    .open-menu i:nth-child(1) {
        top: 25px;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }

    .open-menu i:nth-child(2) {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .open-menu i:nth-child(3) {
        top: 25px;
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
        transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    }

    nav {
        height: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: rgba(0, 47, 77, .25);
        position: fixed;
        top: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: all 3s;
        transition: all 3s;
    }

    .open-menu ~ nav {
        opacity: 1;
        padding: 80px 0;
        z-index: 15;
        height: calc(90vh - 70px);
    }

    nav ul {
        padding: 0 10px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

    nav li {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
    }

    nav li a {
        font-size: 2em;
        display: block;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition: background .3s;
        transition: background .3s;
    }

    nav li:nth-child(odd) a,
    body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:nth-child(5) a {
        background: #962D3E;
    }

    nav li:nth-child(even) a {
        background: #aa3346;
    }

    nav li:nth-child(odd) a:hover {
        background: #9e2f41;
    }

    nav li:nth-child(even) a:hover {
        background: #c53c52;
    }

    nav li.active a,
    body.fp-viewing-fifthSection-1 #menu li:last-child a {
        background: #453659;
    }

    section {
        text-align: center;
        /*background: url('https://unsplash.it/1910/1221?image=626') no-repeat center / cover;*/
    }

    h2 {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-size: 4em;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 2.8em;
    }

    #fp-nav ul li a span,
    .fp-slidesNav ul li a span {
        background: white;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
    }

    #fp-nav ul li a.active span,
    .fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
    #fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
    .fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
        background: transparent;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #24221F;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        nav ul {
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        nav li {
            margin-top: 1px;
        }

        nav li a {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        .scroll-icon {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        html {
            font-size: 50%;
        }

        .open-menu ~ nav {
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

        nav li a {
            padding: 3px;
        }
    }

    .absolute{
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #003eff;
        opacity: 0.3;
        text-align: center;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -100px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/vendors/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="header-top clearfix">
        <h1 class="l-left"><a href="#firstSection">StackOverFlow</a></h1>
        <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="hide">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
                <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">Stackoverflow</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
                <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Suvitruf</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
                <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Igor</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
                <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">StrangerQ</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
                <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">Спасибо</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="fullpage">
    <section class="vertical-scrolling">
        <h2>Stackoverflow</h2>
        <h3>Я крайне признателен всему сообществу stackoverflow<br>
        Просто за то, что Вы есть<br>
        Вы делаете действительно очень важное дело<br>
        В каждом участнике есть та доля альтруизма<br>
        И желание помогать людям<br>
        Которого так сильно нехватает в наше время<br><br>
        Я искренне горжусь, что мог быть частью<br>
        Этого удивительного сообщества</h3>
        <div class="absolute">123</div>
    </section>
    <section class="vertical-scrolling">
        <h2>Suvitruf</h2>
        <h3>Человек искренне преданный сообществу<br>
        Рассудительность и спокойствие <br>
        Делает его действительно необходимым человеком для<br>
        stackoverflow<br><br>
        Продолжайте в том же духе!<br>
        И это сообщество точно сможет стать лучше.<br>
        Благодаря Вам!</h3>
    </section>
    <section class="vertical-scrolling">
        <h2>Igor</h2>
        <h3>Игорь, Вы действительно настоящий альтруист<br>
        Я не уверен, что Вы знаете, что такое сон<br>
        Но действительно приятно видеть Вас<br>
        Почти каждую ночь в "полях"<br>
        Готовым принести людям помощь своим <br>
        Неоспоримым опытом и знаниями!<br><br>
        Ваше стремление помогать<br>
        достойно искренней похвалы<br></h3>
    </section>
    <section class="vertical-scrolling">
        <h2>Stranger in the Q</h2>
        <h3>Челоек с неоспоримым <br>
        Превосходством в графике<br>
        Многие работы просто поражают воображение<br>
        Даже у самых заядлых Backendщиков <br>
        Вызывая желания увлечься<br>
        алгоритмами картинок<br><br>
        А за реализацию google earth<br>
        отдельное спасибо )</h3>
    </section>
    <section class="vertical-scrolling">
        <h2>Все все все</h2>
        <h3>На самом деле<br>
        В данном сообществе я повстречал<br>
        Очень много хороших, добрых<br>
        И отзывчивых людей.<br>
        Qwertiy,Akina,because,Sevastopol`<br>
        MaksLenskiy,humster_spb,ДевочкаСглазамиРебенка<br>
        И многие другие<br>
        Хотелось бы написать о каждом<br>
        Но время ограничено.<br><br>
        Есть, конечно и не совсем добрые люди<br>
        Но и они добавляют особого шарма <br>
        сообществу<br><br>
        Спасибо тебе stackoverflow<br>
        За то, что всегда готов с открытой душой<br>
        Прийти любому на выручку и помощь!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```